# How to create a Decal from a TextureAtlas

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I got a `TextureAtlas` with tiles. From the `TextureAtlas` I want to create `Decals` and position them along the Z-axis.

I cannot find any API to create `Decals` from a `TextureAtlas`.

(I am able to create a `Sprite` from the `TextureAtlas` but a Sprite does not have a Z-component so I cannot place it using `Sprite.setPosition` along the z-axis).

How can I create `Decals` from my `TextureAtlas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a decal class in libgdx, to create a decal, you give it a texture region.

Example:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/SimpleDecalTest.java

To get a texture region from atlas:

```
atlas.findregion("name of your region") ;
```